# How to pause an app while running in the background in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

```
    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(SplashActivity.this);
    // Insert the Ad Unit ID
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
             displayInterstitial();


        }

        private void displayInterstitial() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
    });




    //Declare the timer
    adTimer = new Timer();
    //Set the schedule function and rate
    adTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
            //We must use this function in order to change the text view text
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //if(!isFirstLoad)
                    //{
                    show_ads(typeofAd);
                    //}
                    //isFirstLoad = false;
                }

                private void show_ads(int ad_val) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println(ad_val);
                    Log.i("Ad type"," " + ad_val);
                    switch (ad_val) {
                    case 1:
                            interstitial.loadAd(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        interstitial.loadAd(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build());
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }   
                }

            });
        }
    },
    //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
    1000*60*1, //2 mins
    //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
    1000*60*2); //8 minutes




 public void onDestroy()
 {
        super.onDestroy();

        /*
         * Kill application when the root activity is killed.
         */
       // killApp(true);

    }


 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }// end method onPause

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();


    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        //markerMyLocation = null;
        //myLocationCircle = null;
    }
```

This is my code and i want pause loading app while running in the background, i excuted my code in spice uno m-498 mobile. Itis loading ads even though the app running in background.  please help me..

Comment: You can try and have a check like `if(YourActivity.this.isVisible())` then only show the add.

Comment: I did not set this for particular activity. for the whole app the interstitial ad started here only. so I can't use this code.

Answer (score 1):

I think checking whether your app is in foreground or background everytime before showing an Ads will solve your problem. In below blog they have explained in detail for detecting those states

http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html